# htaccess url redirects with url contains = something

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I want to create some userfriendly new redirects for my website.

My internal search pattern is the following : website.com/search/stuff

I want to add in my htaccess a rule that would redirect : /search=stuff

to : /search/stuff

I was trying the following code into my htaccess file :

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} \\search=([^&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ /search/%1/? [NC,R,L]
```

But that doesnt seem to work... any ideas of where I may be wrong?

Thanks !

Comment: If that URL you want to redirect _really_ is `https://example.com/search=stuff`, then there is no `QUERY_STRING` you can evaluate. A query string is defined by a leading question mark in the URL, so for example by `https://example.com/?search=stuff`.

Comment: Sorted, I needed :

RewriteRule ^search=(.*)$ search/$1 [R=301,L]

Comment: OK, so indeed you did not need a `RewriteCond` and indeed you have a very exotic URL ;-)